# Spotify API - Remove all tracks from temporary playlist

Tags: javascript, spotify

I currently have a temporary playlist but I want a button to remove all the tracks from said playlist. How is this done?

Comment: What version of the Spotify API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using api version 1.0 you can remove all tracks

```
var myTempPlaylist;
models.Playlist.createTemporary("myTempList").done(function(playlist) { 
    myTempPlaylist = playlist;
    playlist.load("tracks").done(function(loadedPlaylist) {
        //....
    });
});

//remove all  existing tracks from the temp playlist
myTempPlaylist.tracks.clear();
```